# Delete child records using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a dropbox clone and I am trying to implement functionality to delete folders in mongodb/mongoose. Specifically, a user can select to delete a parent document that has many children documents. Each document has a field that references the parent document ID. But how can I go about deleting all child documents when deleting a single parent document without taking a massive performance hit.

Is making recursive calls to the database a really bad approach? Or maybe I can populate all the children and then delete them one by one?

Basically I have a tree structure.

Comment: Why is finding children from the parent ID a "massive performance hit"?